# "Cannot find module" errors despite correct paths provided in tsconfig

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, tsconfig, next.js13

I'm running into this recurring issue in my project when it comes to building my next app.

My project structure is the following:

```
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── (buyer)
│   │   ├── (login)
│   │   ├── (vendor)
│   │   ├── api
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   ├── page.module.css
│   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   └── providers.tsx
│   ├── constants
│   │   └── next-auth.ts
├── tailwind.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.spec.json
```

When building this app, I'm running into "cannot find module" errors, mostly complaining about paths not being resolved.

For example:

```
Failed to compile.
       
       ../project-name/src/app/(buyer)/user/page.tsx:4:25
       Type error: Cannot find module '@/constants/next-auth' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
         2 | import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
         3 | 
       > 4 | import { OPTIONS } from '@/constants/next-auth'
           |                         ^
         5 | import { Session } from 'next-auth/core/types'
         6 | 
         7 | const User = async () => {
       Error occurred while trying to run the npx next build 
       Error: Command failed: npx next build
```

The compiler is complaining that there is no path pointing to this module. Let's check the `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "strict": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "incremental": true,
      "types": ["jest", "node"],
      "plugins": [
        {
          "name": "next"
        }
      ],
      "paths": {
        "@/*": ["./src/*"],
        "@/app/*": ["./src/app/*"],
        "@/constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
        ...
      },
    },
    "include": [
      "next-env.d.ts",
      "**/*.ts",
      "**/*.tsx",
      ...
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "jest.config.ts",
      "src/**/*.{spec,test}.ts"
    ]
}
```

I know I'm missing something, I just don't know where.

Comment: Try reversing the order of your `paths`, or removing the first entry.

Comment: unfortunately, same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide one path here.

instead of

```
        "@/*": ["./src/*"],
        "@/app/*": ["./src/app/*"],
        "@/constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
        ...
```

just have

```
"@/*": ["./src/*"]
```

Also make sure that you have defined `baseUrl` properly.